# How to remotely control iPhone from a Windows 10 PC without jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, windows-10

Due to the current scenario, I do not have iPhone with me right now and I need to perform some tests on it using my Windows machine.

I googled a lot but many solutions were saying to jailbreak the device, which is not allowed to do for us.

I tried teamviewer, anydesk and airserver apps as well, but I was only able to see the screen for first two and for airserver it did not get connected even after multiple attempts.

Any help on this would be appreciated, and hope to get to know about an app or service which does not require jailbreak and is either free or at least providing free trial period.